# How to provide Knox public key to clients to use KnoxSSO if it's multiple instanses of Knox in HA mode

Tags: apache-zeppelin, shiro, knox-gateway, apache-knox

### What I've done

1. **I have set up Knox instances [with KnoxSSO](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-6-0/user-guide.html#Pac4j+Provider+-+CAS+/+OAuth+/+SAML+/+OpenID+Connect) and with the same master secrets, accessable through nginx balancer**
2. **I have set up Zeppelin [with shiro](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.10.0/setup/security/shiro_authentication.html#knox-sso) definding in `knoxJwtRealm.publicKeyPath` one of Knox instance's public key**

It works fine while Zeppelin connecting to this instance of Knox. But when it switches to another instance I get an error:

```
KnoxJwtRealm.java[validateToken]:118) - Signature of JWT token could not be verified. Please check the public key
```

So, is it possible to use KnoxSSO with multiple instances of Apache Knox and how to achieve that?

Comment: Sounds like each instance of Knox instance is using a different private key?

Comment: Yes, it was. But after creating wildcard certificate for all instanses of Knox everything works fine. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2):

I have found answer [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Using-single-SSL-Certificate-on-multiple-hosts/td-p/132884)
Creating one wildcard certificate and get it to all Knox instances resolved the problem.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it!